# Python - how to sub select data in matrix

Tags: python, arrays, select, indexing, wolfram-mathematica

I am new in Python... solving this task:

Having dataMatrix - arrays and two lists:`mapRows = ([1, 3, 4,..])`, `mapColumns = ([2, 3, 4,..])`

Now wanted to go over to rows and select only these rows, which are in index list mapRows and from this array take only elements which are in mapColumns

something like `dataMatrix[mapRows:mapColumns]`, but this does not working...

In Mathematica i used for this this syntax: `dataMatrix[[mapRows, mapCulomns]]�����`

Thanx for helping... looking for efficient way, need to do multiple times on large datasets..

L.

Comment: Do you want each column from those rows, e.g. row 1 columns 2,3,4...? Or are the rows and columns paired, e.g. (r,c),(1,2),(3,3),(4,4) .....  A short example of the input and expected output helps us immensely.

Comment: result should again matrix but smaller one, from matrix for example 9x9   if mapRows is 0, 1, 3 and mapColumns 2,3,4 result should be matrix 3x3.. very thanx for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`numpy.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) creates an open mesh that can be used to index *into* the array.  Your data will have to be a [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) ndarray.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(9*9).reshape((9,9))

>>> 
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
       [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
       [54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62],
       [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71],
       [72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]])
>>> map_rows = [1,3,5]
>>> map_columns = [0,4,6]
>>> a[np.ix_(map_rows, map_columns)]
array([[ 9, 13, 15],
       [27, 31, 33],
       [45, 49, 51]])
>>> subset = np.ix_(map_rows, map_columns)
>>> a[subset]
array([[ 9, 13, 15],
       [27, 31, 33],
       [45, 49, 51]])
>>>
```

`numpy` is worth *installing*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the intersection between them you can use `set` :

```
>>> mapRows = ([1, 3, 4,6,8])
>>> mapColumns = ([2, 3, 4,8,0,12])
>>> set(mapRows).intersection(set(mapColumns))
set([8, 3, 4])
```

or use a list comprehension :

```
>>> [i for i in mapRows if i in mapColumns]
[3, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.random.randint(1,10,16)
>>> data.resize(4,4)
>>> data
array([[5, 7, 5, 2],
       [9, 1, 1, 5],
       [9, 9, 7, 2],
       [9, 5, 3, 3]])
>>> mapRows = [0,1,3]
>>> mapCols = [1,3, 2]
>>> data[mapRows,mapCols]
array([7, 5, 3])
```

Comment: for this example result should be array([[7,2,5],[1,5,2],[5,3,3]])

Comment: You mean you want that as output. It can be achieved easily.